# Ruby - how to save values from checkboxes to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox

I have an array of values, like:

```
- @colors.each do |color|
  = check_box_tag 'colors[]', color.id
```

Every time, when I update the values from those checkbox in the DB table, I am doing that by this way:

```
    UserColor.delete_all(['user_id = ?'], current_user.id) #delete all user's rows

    unless params[:colors].nil?
      params[:colors].each do |color|
        UserColor.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :color_id => color)
      end
    end
```

It's the working solution, but I don't like it very much. That's why I would like to ask you, how do you solve this problem and if doesn't exist any some better way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User
  has_many :colors, through: :user_colors
end
```

in controller

```
if params[:colors]
  user = current_user
  user.color_ids = params[:colors]
  user.save
end
```

or u can try

```
current_user.update_attribute(:color_ids, params[:colors]) if params[:colors]
```

Comment: Will this destroy the deselected colors?

Comment: changed my answer a little bit)

Answer (score 1):

I would define a method in the User model

```
def update_colors!(new_color_ids)
    # get an array of the current color ids
    old_color_ids = user_colors.map(&:color_id)

    # destroy colors that appear in the old list but not in the new
    user_colors.where(color_id: old_color_ids - new_color_ids).destroy_all

    # add colors that appear in the new list but not in the old
    (new_color_ids - old_color_ids).each do |add_color_id|
        user_colors.create!(color_id: add_color_id)
    end
end
```

From the controller, just call

```
    current_user.update_colors!(params[:colors])
```

.